# In Emulator OpenCV Manager Error: OpenCV manager is incompatible with this device. Please replace it with an appropriate package

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, android-emulator

I have `Windows7 OS` and I am running `Eclipse` for android latest version. I have installed `OpenCV` and I am trying to run `OpenCV` face-detection sample app in my Emulator.
Detail of Emulator is as follow:

`AVD Name: nexus7virtual`

`Device: Nexus 7(7.02",1200 x 1920: xhdpi)`

`Target: Android 4.4.2-API Level 19`

`CPU/ABI: ARM (armeabi-b7a)`

`Keyboard: H/w keyboard present`

`Skin: HVGA`

`Front Camera: Webcam0`

`Back Camera: None`

`Memory Option: Ram:500           VM Heap:32`

`Internal Storage: 200`

After running the application I am facing the following Error:

```
"OpenCV manager is incompatible with this device. Please replace it with an appropriate package."
```

What is this error and how can I overcome it? Please HELP...